Firefox unable to Download
Firefox stopped beeing able to download.

any download button
right klick on image → Safe Image as

I viewed the firefox help page What to do if you can't download or save files nothing worked.

Finally when I opened firefox from the terminal I noticed this warning: Cannot launch default application: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop was not provided by any .service files
Searching this error brought me to Firefox snap “Show in Folder” and Why can't Firefox snap open other apps or downloads? which led to the solution:
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gtk

